# Set focus bottom of div & allow scrolling back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code at the moment but it doesn't allow for scrolling back, I'm trying to find a way to keep at the bottom of the DIV regardless of how many refreshes occur but to also allow a user to scroll back through the div even if a refresh occurs, I've been unable to find any way around it, the best I can do is this snippet and it does everything except allow a user to scroll back through the DIV, anyone have any suggestions?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(
    function() {
        $("#DLMessageList").show("slow").load("query.php?qid=11");
        $("#mainPane").scrollTop(10000);
    }, 
  2000);
});
</script>

<div id="mainPane">
    <dl id="DLMessageList">
        <dd><span>&lt;core&gt;&nbsp;</span>asdasdasdasd</dd>
        <dt>[13:46:38]&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd><span>&lt;core&gt;&nbsp;</span>dfgsdfg</dd>
        <dt>[13:46:41]&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd><span>&lt;core&gt;&nbsp;</span>fgdfg</dd>
        <dt>[13:46:48]&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd><span>&lt;core&gt;&nbsp;</span>test</dd>
    </div>
</div>
```

There could be hundreds of lines in the `DLMessageList` but the height of the `mainPane` is only 300px.

Comment: Are the refreshes you talk about ajax-refreshes, or full page refreshes?

Comment: @JustusRomijn It's an AJAX request, as in the code above the DIV #mainPane is refreshed using the load() function in the setInterval function above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you want the scrolling position to stick to the bottom after a refresh. Just before your ajax call, check if the div is scrolled all the way down. If it is, then we want to scroll the div also down after the refresh. If not, then the user has scrolled within the div and you don't change the scroll position.

**NOTE**: Not tested, and you may need to subtract the height of your `div` from the scrollHeight value, not sure what it returns.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sticky = true;
  setInterval(
    function() {
        sticky = $("#mainPane")[0].scrollTop == $("#mainPane")[0].scrollHeight;
        $("#DLMessageList").show("slow").load("query.php?qid=11", function(){
            if (sticky){
                $("#mainPane")[0].scrollTop = $("#mainPane")[0].scrollHeight;
            }
        });
    }, 
  2000);
});
```